# Are puranas, radha rani and sai baba fictional or real?

Tags: puranas, krishna, radha

arya samaj says that puranas are manipulated after bhakti moment in 12th century.
And many serials use sources from purans to write their imaginary stories.

-Historical manipulation in purans ?

-Was Radha rani avtar of lakshmi Or not? If Radha existed also , what's her true story and should she be worshipped (non puran source please)

-sai baba was nobel character or evil person who ate meat. Was he sadhu /guru Or person who had bad character?

-what could be cause of changing stories +any historical evidence like mughal Or british interference in our literature or some scholars who misinterpreted a lot

-Also one last question
Is iskocn and sadguru trustworthy or not?

> I don't want to offend anyone I am just too much confused and don't know what to believe

Most of these claims are by arya samaj

Comment: The shirdi person is obviously not god. Historical figure. However, Sri M claims that he is still around there helping people, nonetheless not god, not avatar, nothing. Just a guy who came and died. It’s like if I die, you worship me, that’s pointless.

Comment: You can read all Puranas..Radha is mentioned in Padma, Shiva and other Puranas too..So, not some imaginary character. No historical manipulation happened. Many people don't read Shastras as per sampradaya, hence they can't reconcile properly and feel so many incoherent stories exist. Regarding Sai, he's considered as Dattatreya by Sadhakas and some Yogis. One who understands Datta tattva can see similarities. Literally no influence of britishers or Mughals.. You are also asking too many questions. Limit your questions to one or two.

Comment: What you were told is actually Arya Samaj propaganda utilising the ignorance of a substantial population of North Indian Hindus (who live in the delusion that all about Hinduism is confined to the Gita & Ramacharitamanasa only & unfortunately depend on serials for new info instead of authentic books) to badmouth what the Arya Samaj views as heretical doctrines. This tactic is similar to how Christian missionaries during British rule would defame Hinduism before the world by highlighting a select bad practices like female foeticide prevalent among Jaths & Rajputs.

Comment: Just like Arya Samaj claims that the Hindu texts have been manipulated by non-Hindus to give rise to the current system, Christian missionaries in the past would also claim that the monotheism as described in the Tanakh is the only religion of the mankind which has been manipulated by the Devil to create 'pagan' religions.

Comment: Just like the Arya Samaj claims that their interpretion is the only valid way to God & everybody else (including non-Hindus) are worshipping false gods, Protestant missionaries during British rule also preached the same thing to  others & claimed the non-Protestant Christians & non-Christians are worshipping falso gods.

Comment: Arya Samaj is very much mimicking the Protestant missionaries as it seems. Both denounce the interpretion of scriptures by their predecessors on the grounds of a single issue, both have edited the scripture to suit their own needs & both depend heavily on the interpretation of their founder.

Answer (score 1):

Shankaracharya mentions Radha in his Yamunashtakam stotra -

> "May Yamunā — Whose water is mixed with the cosmetics of sporting
> **Rādhikā**, Who enjoys the continuous touch of Her consort (Kṛṣṇa) which is a luxury for others, Who is mighty enough to penetrate the
> serene seven oceans, and Who is the daughter of Kalinda — washes the
> malice of my mind"

Sloka 6, Yamunashtakam stotra

Comment: Is radha avtar of lakshmi??

Comment: @Adi shankaracharya- Yes.